# How do parse a curl PUT request in Flask-RESTful?

Tags: python, curl, flask, put, flask-restful

How do I save the data uploaded using a curl command like `curl localhost:5000/upload/test.bin --upload-file tmp/test.bin` in a Flask-RESTful PUT handler method?

The code in [Ron Harlev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42286669/4766) to [Flask-RESTful - Upload image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28982974/4766) works with the POST request from `curl -F "file=@tmp/test.bin" localhost:5000/upload/test.bin` (slightly modified below):

```
def post(self, filepath):
    parse = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parse.add_argument('file', type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage, location='files')
    args = parse.parse_args()
    upload_file = args['file']
    upload_file.save("/usr/tmp/{}".format(filepath))
    return ({'filepath': filepath}, 200)
```

But if I try to use the code to handle the PUT request from `curl --upload-file` (changing `post` to `put` above, of course) I get: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'". This refers to the second-last line in the above code.

How do I get a handle to the file data uploaded using `curl --upload-file`, so I can save it to a local file?

**Update:** This works around the problem: `curl --request PUT -F "file=@tmp/test.bin" localhost:5000/upload/test.bin`, but I still don't have an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

curls docs define --upload-file as a PUT http request https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-T.

I'm not sure of the need to handle this through a restful API and I'm pretty sure that's where curl is causing problems, perhaps the assumption that this must be done through flask-restful is holding you back?

maybe try building this as a vanilla flask endpoint instead, this code should work for you.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
...

@app.route('/simpleupload/<string:filepath>', methods=['POST','PUT'])
def flask_upload(filepath):
    with open("/tmp/{}".format(filepath), 'wb') as file:
        file.write(request.stream.read()) 
    return (jsonify({'filepath': filepath}), 200)
```