# Reading image file (file storage object) using OpenCV

Tags: image, opencv, flask, curl

I am sending an image by curl to flask server, i am using this curl command

```
curl -F "file=@image.jpg" http://localhost:8000/home
```

and I am trying to read the file using OpenCV on the server side.

On the server side I handle the image by this code

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['POST'])
def home():
    data =request.files['file']
    img = cv.imread(data)
    fact_resp= model.predict(img)
    return jsonify(fact_resp)
```

I am getting this error-

```
img = cv.imread(data)
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, FileStorage found
```

How do I read the file using OpenCV on the server side?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170752/python-opencv-load-image-from-byte-string for a (simpler) way. Note that having cv2 available implies that numpy (np) is available.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I had similar issues while using opencv with flask server, for that first i saved the image to disk and read that image using saved filepath again using **cv.imread()**

Here is a sample code:

```
data =request.files['file']
filename = secure_filename(file.filename) # save file 
filepath = os.path.join(app.config['imgdir'], filename);
file.save(filepath)
cv.imread(filepath)
```

But now i have got even more efficient approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170752/python-opencv-load-image-from-byte-string) by using **cv.imdecode()** to read image from numpy array as below:

```
#read image file string data
filestr = request.files['file'].read()
#convert string data to numpy array
file_bytes = numpy.fromstring(filestr, numpy.uint8)
# convert numpy array to image
img = cv.imdecode(file_bytes, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Comment: For 2nd trick, use img = cv2.imdecode(npimg,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) for opencv 3.1

Comment: From @user1 the same for version 4.5.5

Answer (score 7):

After a bit of experimentation, I myself figured out a way to read the file using CV2.
For this I first read the image using PIL.image method

This is my code,

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['POST'])
def home():
    data =request.files['file']
    img = Image.open(request.files['file'])
    img = np.array(img)
    img = cv2.resize(img,(224,224))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    fact_resp= model.predict(img)
    return jsonify(fact_resp)
```

I wonder if there is any straight forward way to do this without using PIL.

Answer (score 5):

So incase you want to do something like ,

```
file = request.files['file']
img = cv.imread(file)
```

then do it like this

```
import numpy as np
file = request.files['file']
file_bytes = np.fromfile(file, np.uint8)
file = cv.imdecode(file_bytes, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Now you don't need to do `cv.imread()` again, but can use this in the next line of codes.

This applies to OpenCV v3.x and onwards

Answer (score 1):

Two-line solution, change grayscale to what you need

```
 file_bytes = numpy.fromfile(request.files['image'], numpy.uint8)
 # convert numpy array to image
 img = cv.imdecode(file_bytes, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```