# Python flask request post image loading using cv2.imread ERROR

Tags: python, post, flask, request, opencv

I'm building a flask image classification service and I'm trying to use cv2 to read the POSTed image.

Here's the postman post setup:
[image]

On the server side, I have

```
@app.route("/inference", methods=["POST"])
def inference():

    img = request.files["img"]
    img = cv2.imread(str(img))[...,::-1] # 1
    img = cv2.imread(img)[...,::-1]      # 2
    ...
```

I wanted to use cv2 because I will needed to resize the image later. However, I'm getting errors:

for "# 1", I'm getting:

```
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

for "# 2", I'm getting:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Note that `cv2.imread()` is working fine on my local, and I suspect it's the file/class type of the request object.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The datastructure of `request.files` is a [FileStorage](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage). maybe `request.files["img"].stream.read()` to get a bytestream

Comment: @Patricio Thank for the hint! I think I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515243/reading-image-file-file-storage-object-using-cv2. I'm going to try to see if it works or not.